# Drawing arrows between features in different layers

Tags: qgis, point

I have two shapefile layers showing the position of point features at two times. I would like to draw arrows showing the direction of travel of each feature (i.e. the arrows point from their position in layer 1 to their position in layer 2). I was able to do this several years ago in QGIS but I have forgotten how and I can't figure it out. I would preferably like to do it in QGIS again (I am using version 3.12), but open to using ArcGIS Pro as well.

Comment: Do they share an id? Or how are they linked?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] this to remove the second platform (Pro) that makes it two questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The points in the two layers that should be connected must share an attribute with a common value, e.g. an id. Then use QGIS expressions with [Geoemtry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#hard-fa-geometry-generator-symbology) or [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) (see here [for differences](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)) with the following expression and style the line as arrow.

*In my case, I have a layer `earlier` (with the field containing common attributes called `attribute_name_earlier`) and one `later` (`attribute_name_later`). I run the expression an the layer `earlier`. Change the values in the expression to match your layer and attribute-field names:*

```
make_line (
    $geometry,
    geometry (
        get_feature(
            'later',  -- change the name to match your layer name
            'attribute_name_later',  -- change the name of the attribute
            "attribute_name_earlier"  -- change the name of the attribute
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thank you.